# Decrementing elements in an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to figure out how to decrement all the values in an array list.

Example:

index:

1  =  10

2  =  7

3  =  9

4  =  3

and i want to loop through and decrement them all by one.

I have tried

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   if(heapIndex.get(i) !=-1){
   heapIndex.set(heapIndex.get(i), heapIndex.get(i)-1);
}
```

not sure why this does not work
Note: -1 is a special value.

Comment: Come on...Go through a tutorial on lists and iteration.

Comment: Well, use a loop...like you said.

Comment: I'm not going to participate in Java questions on SO any more ...

Comment: `for` seems like a good start

Comment: Do you need a solution that's generalizable to arrays other than { null, 10, 7, 9, 3 }?

Comment: a[1]--;a[2]--;a[3]--;a[4]--;

Comment: heapIndex.set(i, heapIndex.get(i)-1);

Comment: If heapIndex is your array, and you're using the *value* stored at heapIndex[i] as the *index* where you're storing the value of heapIndex[i] - 1, you're in for a heap of indexes. And a heap of trouble, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this

```
List<Integer> al = Arrays.asList( // First, get a
                                  // List of Integers.
    new Integer[] { 10, 7, 9, 3 }); // From the question
System.out.println(al); // print the List.
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
  Integer v = al.get(i); // get the element.
  v = v - 1; // Update the value.
  al.set(i, v); // Update the List.
}
System.out.println(al); // print the List.
```

Which prints

```
[10, 7, 9, 3]
[9, 6, 8, 2]
```